# CakePHP3 Cache::read() keys inside groups can't be read

Tags: caching, cakephp-3.0

Hi everyone i work with cakephp3 and i have implemented the cache from [doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/caching.html)
Here is my cache configuration using groups

```
 Cache::config('users', [
        'className' => 'File',
        'duration' => '+1 hours',
        'path' => CACHE,
        'serialize' => true,
        'groups' => ["users_$groupId"]
    ]);
```

And here is my key is created in a folder whose name is the name of the group

[image]

Now the prob is when i want to read the key using

```
 Cache::read('my_key')
```

Doest not work because the key is stored in the folder inside Cache folder

NB: When I haven't used the groups in the cache it works well, I can read my key because the key is stored directly in the cache folder.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your custom config when reading from the cache, otherwise the `default` config will be used, which very likely points to the normal `cache` folder, hence it "works" when you don't specify any groups in your custom config.

```php
Cache::read('my_key', 'users')
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Caching > Reading From a Cache](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/caching.html#reading-from-a-cache)**
- **[Cookbook > Caching > Using Groups](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/caching.html#using-groups)**